# Recent Google keyboard update broke plugged HID devices

Tags: android, android-keypad

I'm curious if more people noticed this. If you plug HID input device (keypad, keyboard, barcode scanner, etc) a recent market update to Google Keyboard broke backwards compatibility. HID devices that emit Enter code/action all started putting "new lines" which broke apps. In our case, users cannot scan barcodes anymore. The scanner itself works, but the input field doesn't produce any action, just a new line is entered after the scanned text shows up.

The EditText already uses below attributes none of which matter anymore:

> singleLine="true"
>   android:inputType="text"
>   android:imeOptions="actionSearch"

Temp. fix is to install a third party keyboard such as Hacker's Keyboard.

Specifically, there is no callback after registering with [setOnEditorActionListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setOnEditorActionListener(android.widget.TextView.OnEditorActionListener)). In my case, this is reproducible by having EditText placed in a Fragment:

> [...] This will be called when the enter key is pressed, or when
>   an action supplied to the IME is selected by the user. **Setting this
>   means that the normal hard key event will not insert a newline into
>   the text view**, even if it is multi-line.

Comment: I am observing a similar issue in my application. Using third party keyboards fixes the problem. Did you come across any alternate fix? More details here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37949252/where-does-default-input-keyboard-sit-in-the-flow-for-dispatching-key-events-on

Comment: No alternate fix other than installing another keyboard.

Comment: Can you check what is the root cause of the issue in case of your app? If there is a missing key event then it can be fixed.

Comment: The missing event wasn't "missing" for 3- years. If the fix requires changing code that's what I referred to as "broken backwards compatibility". Plus, how can a single-line EditText be producing multiple lines now? The whole thing is a mess and work-around if any will be a hack.