# Where does default input keyboard sit in the flow for dispatching key events on android?

Tags: android, keyevent

In one of my Custom view, inheriting from a View group, I was getting Key_Down and Key_Up events for a Tab key in dispatchKeyEvent method.

A latest update on Google Keyboard upgraded it from 4.0.* to 5.0.*. Post this update, I am not getting Key_Down in dispatchKeyEvent in the ViewGroup. I have checked that I am getting both Key_Down and Key_Up events in dispatchKeyEventPreIme in ViewGroup. Also, I am not handling Key_Down in OnKeyPreIme in my Custom View.

I am not able to figure out, who is eating away Key_Down event in this case? I continue to get Key_Up event like before.
For this, I am trying to understand where input keyboard sit in the flow for dispatching key events. Couldn't find much info regarding this on web.

Would appreciate any help/pointers. Thanks!